# c++ static variable in shared lib and better visibility

Tags: c++, static, shared-libraries

Have a shared lib A contains static data S, A is shared linked with shared lib B and shared lib C. The main process will dynamically load B.so and C.so at run time.During test, looks like data S is shared between B and C. But I don't know why.

My first question is: i learned that shared lib code is shared (only one copy of text in memory), does it mean the data in shared lib should be duplicated if multiply lib use it? like the static data S.

Second question is: currently i declare data S as

```
struct S {
    static S1 s1;
    static S2 s2;
    ...
}
```

in A.h file and define them in A.cpp file. It maybe not obvious for people who read this code to get that these static data are shared rather than different compilation unit will have its own copy. Is there a decent way to make it more obvious?

Thank you!

Comment: i think static objects  are duplicated everywhere when they are needed.  Scoped static objects are stored in the the same location of `S`  and are accessible as global variables. So they look like being shared between your `B` and `C`.

Comment: why does `s1` and `s2` been shared between `B` and `C`, I thought `A` and `B` would have its own copy. Is that related with that `A` is shared linked by `B` and `C` respectively?

Comment: Yes. The implementation of shared libs is usually that it only gets loaded once in the program even if many components, like other shared libs, use the lib. So when you load B it also loads A and rewrites all the references in B to A to point to where A was loaded. Then when you load C it sees that A is already present so it only rewrites the references to A to where A is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that on Windows the usual situation is that dynamic libraries do not share variables, only functions.  But the Unix model is that any linking has the same semantics: all the dependencies for each module are loaded, but are not *included* in their clients as might cause duplication.

This is normally considered a feature: if your library has global state (*e.g.*, to protect a shared resource like a configuration file), it’s good to have exactly one (per process) in all situations.  As for “obvious”, you should generally assume your clients know this (to the extent they need to be aware of globals in your library at all).

Of course, an even better idea is to avoid such global state: instead have the client maintain it (with functions provided by the library, of course).  Some such shared state naturally becomes local to some nearby stack frame, playing a role like the Builder pattern.  Others can be made thread-local (perhaps by simply being local in a thread’s initial function).

Anything that actually needs to be process-wide ultimately becomes a local in `main`, leaving the rest of the code cast as stateless, composable libraries.  (Such variables could instead be `static` in the translation unit containing `main` and not much else, but that just constrains their initialization.)